# Redirect sub-domain to a file in PHP/.HTaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

i've the following URL API's:
api.sandox.mypage.com (this sub-domain redirects to root's folder www/api/sandbox/)
api.mypage.com (this sub-domain redirects to the root's folder www/api/live/) -> Production API

Each API has services like payments/request_payment (to request a new payment), /payments/1/ (where 1 is the id of the payment to get that payment's info), /company/1 (where 1 is the id of a company to get that company's info)

What is the best way to to that? because actually i can only put the real .php path file, like payments/request_payment.php, /payments/getPaymentInfo.php and /company/getCompanyInfo.php, i don't want to use the .php extension and use the schema that i told before.

What's the best option to do that, using **HTACCESS** files or **Routing** with PHP and how can i do that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the best way to do what?

Comment: For the subdomains, use `<VirtualHost>` in apache.conf, for the uri use `ModRewrite` and for the routing use PHP `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`  or similiar variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these rules to your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

# for payments/request_payment
RewriteRule ^payments/request_payment$ /payments/request_payment.php [L]

# for /payments/1/
RewriteRule ^payments/([0-9]+)/?$ /payments/getPaymentInfo.php?id=1 [L,QSA]

# for /company/1/
RewriteRule ^company/([0-9]+)/?$ /company/getCompanyInfo.php?id=1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: But that only works for the principal domain, or not? i want it for the sub-domains: api.mypage.com and api.sandox.mypage.com.

Comment: @gustavomanolo if you put that in the document root for both domains, it'll work for both domains